# Configure Jetty 9.4 event listener

Tags: servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I want to listen to `contextInitialized()` and `contextDestroyed()` events. I created `jetty.xml` file where I want to specify the class that will be responsible for listening. The error message I get: `Unknown tag: listener`.

The content of the file:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <listener>
    <listener-class>test.Application</listener-class>
  </listener>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Configuration>` is for configuring a specific object in Jetty.

That syntax has a DTD that explains what you are allowed to use as far as what XML elements.

`<listener>` is not available in that DTD.

That's the reason for the error `Unknown tag: listener`

Now, lets dig a bit deeper...

Why do you want a Listener that listens for `contextInitialized()` and `contextDestroyed()`?

I assume you want a [`javax.servlet.ServletContextInitializer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) based on those method names.

That's only available in a specific webapp, not for all webapps.

The most common way to configure that is in the webapp's own `WEB-INF/web.xml`

That's where your `<listener>` block needs to be.